# The letter after Double Quotes

Tags: .net, vb.net

```
Dim someChar as Char
someChar = "L"c
```

I am interested in the c after the double quotes.  I know it casts it as a Char.  What is that called?  I would like to find out if there are others to know about.

Thanks

Comment: This is a VB.NET feature so I have removed the [c#] tag.

Comment: It doesn't really "cast" it, it declares it as a character literal. You could cast, too; this would be functionally equivalent, but is not the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the [complete list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9cz43ek.aspx):

```
Literal type character    Data type    Example
----------------------    ---------    -------
S                         Short        I = 347S
I                         Integer      J = 347I
L                         Long         K = 347L
D                         Decimal      X = 347D
F                         Single       Y = 347F
R                         Double       Z = 347R
US                        UShort       L = 347US
UI                        UInteger     M = 347UI
UL                        ULong        N = 347UL
C                         Char         Q = "."C
```